# Is [temp.dep.type]/p7 covered by [temp.res]/p8?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

[[temp.dep.type]/p7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#7):

> If a *qualified-id* in which the *nested-name-specifier* refers to the
> current instantiation is not a member of the current instantiation or
> a member of an unknown specialization, the program is ill-formed even
> if the template containing the *qualified-id* is not instantiated; no
> diagnostic required. Similarly, if the *id-expression* in a class
> member access expression for which the type of the object expression
> is the current instantiation does not refer to a member of the current
> instantiation or a member of an unknown specialization, the program is
> ill-formed even if the template containing the member access
> expression is not instantiated; no diagnostic required. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class T> class A {
>   typedef int type;
>   void f() {
>     A<T>::type i;               // OK: refers to a member of the current instantiation
>     typename A<T>::other j;     // error: neither a member of the current instantiation nor
>                                 // a member of an unknown specialization
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

[[temp.res]/p8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#8) (irrelevant part is omitted):

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template
> to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the
>   template is not instantiated, or
>
> ...
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> int j;
> template<class T> class X {
>   void f(T t, int i, char* p) {
>     t = i;          // diagnosed if X​::​f is instantiated, and the assignment to t is an error
>     p = i;          // may be diagnosed even if X​::​f is not instantiated
>     p = j;          // may be diagnosed even if X​::​f is not instantiated
>   }
>   void g(T t) {
>     +;              // may be diagnosed even if X​::​g is not instantiated
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> ...
>
> — *end example* ]

---

In my opinion, if the conditions in [temp.dep.type]/p7 are met, then no valid specialization can be generated for this template (for example, in the *example* of [temp.dep.type]/p7, no valid specialization can be generated for the declaration `typename A<T>::other j;`), thus the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required according to [temp.res]/p8.

So is [temp.dep.type]/p7 covered by [temp.res]/p8? If not, could you please give an example that [temp.dep.type]/p7 covers but [temp.res]/p8 does not cover?

Comment: I suspect that you're right: being neither a member of the current specialization nor a member of an unknown specialization just means "not found and no dependent bases to search later", and that can't be a good thing.  To make matters worse, the example is not strictly relevant: there is no *qualified-id* in `typename A<T>::other`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [temp.dep.type]/p7 is indeed covered by [temp.res]/p8.

Now [temp.dep.type]/p7 is completely removed through [P1787](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html), and part of example is added to that in [temp.res]/8.